Esp32-SE transmitter Lo-Fi (LoRaWan)
I have an "ESP32-SE Lo-Fi"
I need to use the internal antenna of this ESP to send data to a database (LoRaWan)
The database is not made by me but I'm sure it works.
I have tried to use this code to send data to the LoRaWan but it tells me some error that I am not able to comprehend.
Here is my code (for safety issue I have deleted the AppEUI, DevEUI, and APPKEY).
#include <lmic.h>
#include <hal/hal.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// Remplir avec les valeurs obtenues lors de l'enregistrement de votre appareil sur TTN
static const u1_t PROGMEM APPEUI[8] = { 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x };
void os_getArtEui (u1_t* buf) { memcpy(buf, APPEUI, 8);}

static const u1_t PROGMEM DEVEUI[8] = { 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x };
void os_getDevEui (u1_t* buf) { memcpy(buf, DEVEUI, 8);}

static const u1_t PROGMEM APPKEY[16] = { 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x, 0x };
void os_getDevKey (u1_t* buf) { memcpy(buf, APPKEY, 16);}

// Pin mapping
const lmic_pinmap lmic_pins = {
    .nss = 5, // GPIO5 (IO5)
    .rxtx = LMIC_UNUSED_PIN,
    .rst = 14, // GPIO14 (IO14)
    .dio = {2, 15, 4}, // DIO0: GPIO2 (IO2), DIO1: GPIO15 (IO15), DIO2: GPIO4 (IO4)
};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println(F("Starting"));

    // Initialisation de LMIC
    os_init();
    Serial.println(F("LMIC initialized"));

    // Réinitialiser l'état MAC. Les sessions et les transferts de données en attente seront annulés.
    LMIC_reset();
    Serial.println(F("LMIC reset"));

    // Désactiver la validation de la vérification de lien
    LMIC_setLinkCheckMode(0);

    // TTN utilise SF9 pour sa fenêtre RX2.
    LMIC.dn2Dr = DR_SF9;
    Serial.println(F("Data rate set"));

    // Définir le débit de données et la puissance de transmission (note: txpow semble être ignoré par la bibliothèque)
    LMIC_setDrTxpow(DR_SF7, 14);
    Serial.println(F("Setup Complete"));
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println(F("Running loop"));
    os_runloop_once();
    delay(100);  // Ajout d'un délai pour éviter de surcharger le CPU
}

I downloaded the "MCCI Arduino LoRaWan Library" and the "esp32" board.
Here is a link to the board documentation.
Here is my error log.
Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x42002258  PS      : 0x00060e34  A0      : 0x82002499  A1      : 0x3fcebfa0  
A2      : 0x3c030304  A3      : 0x00000035  A4      : 0x3fc95ad0  A5      : 0x00000000  
A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x00000000  A8      : 0x82002258  A9      : 0x3fcebf80  
A10     : 0x3fc95ad0  A11     : 0x00000002  A12     : 0x0000000a  A13     : 0x0000ff00  
A14     : 0x00ff0000  A15     : 0xff000000  SAR     : 0x00000016  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400556d5  LEND    : 0x400556e5  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  


Backtrace: 0x42002255:0x3fcebfa0 0x42002496:0x3fcebfc0 0x42001ae0:0x3fcebfe0 0x42005eea:0x3fcec010


Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x403796b2  PS      : 0x00060c34  A0      : 0x8200d730  A1      : 0x3fcf4360
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x420198e4  A4      : 0x00060c20  A5      : 0x00000001  
A6      : 0x80000000  A7      : 0x3fc92f88  A8      : 0x8200ca3a  A9      : 0x3fcf4320  
A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x3fc93030  A12     : 0x3fc93030  A13     : 0x00000000  
A14     : 0x00060c20  A15     : 0x3fc93040  SAR     : 0x0000001d  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x00000000  LEND    : 0x00000000  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtracx�x����x���������x����xx�x���x����xx�x�����������x��������x������x���x����xx�x���������x����������x���x�x���x����xx�x�����xx�x�xx�xx�xx�xx�xxx�xx���x��x�xxx���x�xx��x��������������x�x�xx������x����xx��x�xx�x�x�xx�x��xx�xx�x�x�x��x�x�xx�x�xx�x���ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
Build:Mar 27 2021
rst:0xc (RTC_SW_CPU_RST),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x4200cdff
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fce3818,len:0x508
load:0x403c9700,len:0x4
load:0x403c9704,len:0xad0
load:0x403cc700,len:0x29e4
entry 0x403c9880
Starting
FAILURE 
c:\Users\tomwi\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCCI_LoRaWAN_LMIC_library\src\lmic\oslmic.c:53
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1).

I am really sorry for my English and wish that you can help me.
Thanks in advance

It should be memcpy_P instead of memcpy if the data is stored in PROGMEM. You are using ESP32, so remove the PROGMEM as it doesn't need for ESP32.

I applied the modifications you gave me, unfortunately the result did not change. I think pins are probably poorly defined but I can't understand the pin table
